# Borders not shown in Firefox with border-collapse on table, position: relative on tbody, or background-color on cell

Tags: css, firefox, border

Consider the following HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        TABLE.data TD.priceCell
        {
            background-color: #EEE;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000;
        }
    
        div.datagrid table
        {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    
        div.datagrid table tbody
        {
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contents" class="datagrid">
        <table class="data" id="tableHeader">
            <thead>
                <tr class="fixed-row">
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th class="HeaderBlueWeekDay">Price</th>
                    <th class="HeaderBlueWeekDay">Discount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="font-style: italic;">
                    <td>Keyboard</td>
                    <td class="priceCell">20</td>
                    <td style="border-right: #3D84FF 1px solid; border-left: #3D84FF 1px solid;" class="priceCell">2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the last cell has a left and a right border in its inline style. You (or at least I) would expect this to be visible. In IE, this is the case. But in Firefox (6), this is not. You can solve this by:

- Removing position relative on `div.datagrid table tbody` in the CSS
- Changing `div.datagrid table tbody` to `div.datagrid table` in the CSS
- Removing the `background-color` on `table.data td.priceCell` in the CSS
- Removing the `border-collapse` on `div.datagrid table` in the CSS

This is a simplified version of our code; we also solved it (by choosing option 2). But what I'm wondering about is:

- Is this a bug in Firefox?
- Is this a bug in IE?

And especially: what is the reason Firefox wouldn't show the borders when the CSS is as it is?

Comment: Don't ask me why, but when i moved the `border-collapse` property from the `div.datagrid table` into the `table.data` itself in the CSS above, it worked alright. Maybe there's someone else here who can explain... (i'm on Firefox 5)

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. I suspect this is a bug, as relative positioning should not affect borders, but I made a simplified test case and all 4 browsers displayed it differently! (Fx6, Op 11.50, IE8, Chrome 15) Test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/76Qb7/9/

Comment: Just ran into this issue … funny that a firefox bug persists over such a timespan.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This looks like a Firefox bug to me.  The backgrounds are painting over the borders; you can see it if you use a translucent background color.

I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688556

Comment: I ran in the same issue. It is still not fixed by Firefox. Seems they don't take it seriously enough while it is a big design issue when using the :nth-child(odd) selector as well to add a background to only the odd rows. I need the border as well to make it perfect. Thansk for filing the bug!

Comment: FYI, still current 9 years later.

Comment: FYIA, still current 11 years later.

Comment: FYI, still occurring after 12 years later.

Comment: Still happening in June, 2023 ( 12 year after )

Answer (score 219):

Just ran into this issue and came to a css only solution:
just add `background-clip: padding-box` to your `td` element.

See this article for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-clip

Comment: Huh, I don't get it. The docs say it specifies whether the background extends *underneath* the border. I get the impression it's rendered on top of the border.

Comment: Best CSS only solution i've found. Thanks for sharing @medoingthings

Comment: This is far from the solution. There is a gap between the border and the box. That makes the border color highlighted and little shadow effect. We don't want that.

Answer (score 19):

Just to put all in one place.

The problem is produced when you have a cell with position relative inside a table with collapsed borders (as Boris indicated and filled in the bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688556)

This can be easily solved using CSS as indicated by user2342963 (Adding background-clip: padding-box to the cell).

You can see the problem (with Firefox) and the fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramiro_conductiva/XgeAS/

```
table {border-spacing: 0px;}
td {border: 1px solid blue; background-color: yellow; padding: 5px;}
td.cellRelative {position: relative;}
td.cellRelativeFix {background-clip: padding-box;}
table.tableSeparate {border-collapse: separate;}
table.tableCollapse {border-collapse: collapse;}

<table class="tableSeparate">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellRelative">position: relative</td>
            <td>position: static</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="tableCollapse">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellRelative">position: relative</td>
            <td>position: static</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="tableCollapse">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellRelative cellRelativeFix">position: relative</td>
            <td>position: static</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works to fix the bug in FF but in IE there is an ugly white border inside the regular border how do we fix that?

Comment: Thanks you so much. Your code helped me a lot time

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in firefox and hopefully they fix it soon.  But in the mean time I was able to fix this issue for me by setting my `td` cells to `position: static`. Hopefully that will help someone else.

```
td {
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: If you use pseudo-elements like `::before` or `::after` on the same `td`, `position: static` messes these stylings up. `background-clip: padding-box` is safer.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is to correct colspan errors in your table markup.

Apparently can colspan errors cause the same effects with hidden borders when using border-collapse: collapse;

I was directed to the right solution through http://www.codingforums.com/html-and-css/46049-border-collapse-hiding-some-outside-borders.html.

In my table I had written <th colspan="9"> when there was only 8 columns.

That caused error (hidden right border) in

- Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit)
- Vivaldi 1.2.490.43 () (32-bit)

but rendered with right borders in

- Firefox 44.0.2
- IE 11 (11.420.10586.0)
- Edge 25.10586.0.0

Comment: Removing border-collapse: collapse from table element helped us

Comment: Other syntax errors apparently trigger this too. Considering @pekaaw's advice, I proofread my HTML and found that I had `<thead>` where I meant to have `</thead>`. Fixing that typo fixed the border problem!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this issue is to do something like this.

Note the position: relative property in the "thead" and the "tbody' elements, those are important. So are the border-collapse and background-clip properties. Works with background-color on all and alternating rows.

```
table {
  width: 100% !important;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: unset !important;

  thead {
    position: relative;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;

    tr {
      th {
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border-top: 1px solid #737373!important;
        border-left: 1px solid #737373!important;
        border-right: none !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;

        &:last-child {
          border-right: 1px solid #737373!important;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  tbody {
    position: relative;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;

    tr {
      &:last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #737373!important;
        }
      }

      td {
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border-top: 1px solid #737373!important;
        border-left: 1px solid #737373!important;
        border-right: none !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;

        &:last-child {
          border-right: 1px solid #737373!important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding another solution for this (old) issue: This happened to me today, because I have a somewhat complicated table with multiple tbody.
The only issue was actually that I had an opened tbody tag that was not closed. I deleted that tag and the borders re-appeared, without needing to change anything in my CSS.
To clarify, my structure was something like:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Val3</td><td>Val4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me add border-collapse attribute to separate inside table solved the problem

Like this:

```
margin-bottom: 0;
color: #333333;
font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif !important;
border-collapse: separate;
```

Where as in chrome, we don't need to set this attribute and works fine even without mentioning too.

Answer (score 0):

The table body should not have
"position":"relative".