# CSS: strange cell border behavior in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have table with a few hundreds of rows. I set up CSS border to every **td** inside it. In Google Chrome, it works just fine:
http://aciai.me/i/gwmYS.png

There is same rows on very same page in Firefox:
http://aciai.me/i/VEArL.png

Notice right border of table on second screenshot. I tried make changes via Firebug: make table narrower, *!important* for cell border... nothing helped. In addition... it happens random table rows with every refresh of Firefox. :(

Do you have any idea what's going here? Any way to fix this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Source code here: http://download.cvrez.cz/stackoverflow_css_cell_border.zip

Comment: can you provide your code to us?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517127/borders-not-shown-in-firefox-with-border-collapse-on-table-position-relative-o  -  This may help you.

Comment: is your page scaled down?? can you try changing border-width and see if problem persisits

Comment: @FrankProvost Sure, I updated original post with for whole page. Please, don't mind language (it's Czech). :) Problem appears in this off-line copy too.

Comment: @YogeshKhatri: There's no scaling in my Firefox and I have the latest version. I noticed this behavior months later but it wasn't bugging so much.

Comment: @jaCUBE - The only issue I see is that the rows styled by "contract" are missing two cells and the rows styled by "section" are short by one `colspan`.  There were no issues displaying its borders in FF32, GC37, or IE9-11, just those missing cells.

Comment: @Zulu Thanks, it really seems like some lead. My **tbody** has no relative position, but when I load page, disable border-collapse through Firebug and then just enable it again (kind of restart) it's alright out of the blue.

It seems to be Firefox bug but I don't know what causes it and I can't avoid it therefore.

Comment: @coderboi_89: Thanks to your report, I tried start my Firefox with completely new profile and it works as charm now. Return of my old profile means return of this strange problem. So, it seems I can blame one of my FF extensions. Thank you for your help guys, I go try find my evil plug-in.

Comment: @jaCUBE - Try adding half your extensions back, and then keep halving the remaining amount until you can determine which is causing the issue, if any.  Could could also be a corrupted profile (saw this stuff happen a lot as a service desk agent).