# Making an HTML table scalable across resolutions

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table that maintains the same aspect ratio and size across multiple resolutions.

Here are a few characteristics of the table I'm building:

1. There can be any number of rows and columns.
2. Each td should ALWAYS have a minimum height of 50px and a minimum width of 120px;
3. Certain `<td>` would have a div with the entire height of the td.
4. The table should scale up with 5:12 aspect ratio while occupying as much screen width and height as possible.

A fiddle demonstrating what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/ymbkpstn/

Is this possible in pure CSS? Preferably CSS 2.1?

Comment: Why would you want to do it in CSS 2.1? It's CSS3 now <.<

Comment: why not using `display:table` and `display:table-cell` works in IE8 as well. check http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Atable

Comment: I said preferably, I'm fine with CSS3 if there's no other choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now I had discarded the idea of using `position:absolute` for the div since when you add `position:relative` to a `td` with border-collapse, it made the borders invisible. After some googling, I found that the solution for that involves using `background-clip:padding-box` on the td. This however, causes the child `div` to be 1px smaller than the parent `td`. So my final solution was to apply the following css for the div:

```
td div
{
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  bottom:0;
  left:-1px;
  right:0px;
}
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ymbkpstn/22/

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy just following css will help you.

```
td div
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
td
{
    position:relative;
}
```

Check [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ymbkpstn/1/)

Comment: Adding position relative somehow makes the borders disappear...
See:http://jsfiddle.net/ymbkpstn/18/

Comment: @Erric It is because you remove `border-collapse:collapse;` from table.

Comment: But I need border-collapse, anyway saw the solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517127/borders-not-shown-in-firefox-with-border-collapse-on-table-position-relative-o

Comment: @Erric then use `background-clip: padding-box;` Check : http://jsfiddle.net/ymbkpstn/21/

Comment: That's exactly the content of the link I posted.