# TD background color causing borders to disappear

Tags: html, css, colors, border, background-color

I have a large HTML table that is created dynamically. 
The table has a standard structure, incl. `colgroup`, `thead` and `tbody` and the below styles.

So far everything works as intended but when I add the class "bgGrey" to the TDs in one column (see below) in order to give the cells in this column a background color (which is only needed on one column) then **all borders of this column disappear in IE11**, except for the left border, and the **`:hover::before` style doesn't work anymore in Chrome** (version 43).
Without adding the class `"bgGrey"` I have no issues in both browsers.

It seems that somehow the background color overlaps the border causing this.

**My CSS (relevant part):**

```css
#myTable, #myTable tbody, #myTable thead, #myTable tr {
    width: 100%;
}
#myTable, #myTable th, #myTable td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
}
#myTable {
    font-size: 14px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#myTable th.editable:hover::before, #myTable td.editable:hover::before {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
#myTable .th1 {
    padding: 2px;
}
#myTable .th2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.bgGrey {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

**My HTML (example TR):**

```
<tr>
    // ...
    <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
    <td class="bgGrey editable txtCenter"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
    <td class="editable txtRight"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
    // ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please remove `border-collapse: collapse;` from `#myTable td`, which causes the border to disappear. Avoid giving that for `td`.

Add like this instead:

```css
#myTable, #myTable th, #myTable td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative; //REMOVE THIS
}
```

Also please can you try removing "position:relative" from the CSS?

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried but this doesnt change it.

Comment: Can you please share url?

Comment: I am sorry, in this case I can't as the code is too large and the table is created dynamically but all TRs are set up the same way and I posted all the relevant styles.

Comment: Oh if url is there i think it will be simple to edit and show you than trial and error thats why

Comment: Did you tried removing the position:relative css given?

Comment: I cannot remove this as it is needed for the hover color.

Comment: I think we can give hover in other way without using position:absolute for td

Comment: Thanks - this helped me to find a workaround. It works fine now.

Comment: Removing the *what* from the CSS?

Answer (score 68):

I just came upon this problem myself, but I didn't like the solution presented here, so I kept googling. I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16337203/1156476

Here, a simple addition to the table cell fixes the borders:

```
table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
  background-clip: padding-box; /* Add this line */
}
```

Check browser support at [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip)

And an explanation of the property can be found at [Standardista](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties#bg9)

Comment: Linked explanation gives me a security warning, here is an article on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-clip