# Relative <th> loses border when Absolute <div> is nested within

Tags: html, css, html-table, position, border

I have a TH parent with DIV child.

The TH must be position:relative so that its child DIV can align to it with position:absolute.

However, when I add position:relative to the TH, it loses its border properties completely.

This happens regardless of whether or not the TH text content, DIV, A, or SVG are present (see markup).

I'd like to know how to stop this odd behavior! Thank you.

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POpEeZ)**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".table-body").scroll(function() {
    $(".table-header")[0].style.top = (this.scrollTop) + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
tr,
td,
thead,
tbody {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 16px 24px 16px 24px;
}

th a {
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

svg * {
  transition: fill .2s ease;
}

.filters-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
}

th a:hover>svg * {
  fill: #333333;
}

thead tr {
  height: 36px;
}

#bodytable tbody {
  display: block;
}

.table-header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.table-body {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

.header-cell {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-width: 330px;
}

.body-cell {
  min-width: 330px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-body">
  <table id="bodytable">
    <thead class="table-header">
      <tr>
        <th class="header-cell col1">One
          <a>
            <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="4px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 4 20" enable-background="new 0 0 4 20" xml:space="preserve">
        <circle fill="#666666" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
        <circle fill="#666666" cx="2" cy="10" r="2"/>
        <circle fill="#666666" cx="2" cy="18" r="2"/>
       </svg>
          </a>
          <div class="filters-menu"></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This script causes the table's header elements to fix vertically but scroll horizontally alongside its body elements.

Comment: the TR has it's border properties in your example

Comment: see my answer. turned out to be a firefox-specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found out this is a bug in Firefox where the background of a TH paints over borders when positioned relative. Should've searched, sorry mods.

Confirmed via the use of a transparent rgba() background property on class .header-cell

See this stack question for more:

[Borders not shown in Firefox with border-collapse on table, position: relative on tbody, or background-color on cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517127/borders-not-shown-in-firefox-with-border-collapse-on-table-position-relative-o)

And this bug filing by user [**Boris Zbarsky**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720912/boris-zbarsky):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688556

Sad that it's still broken over 6 years later!

**For now, giving the background-color property to the THEAD parent element seems to be a good workaround**

Answer (score 0):

For firefox, you may use a `gradient` and `background-size` as a workaround:

```
  background-color:#f8f8f8;/* older browser */
  background:linear-gradient(#f8f8f8,#f8f8f8 )no-repeat center / 100% 100% ;/* firefox understands this */
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".table-body").scroll(function() {
    $(".table-header")[0].style.top = (this.scrollTop) + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
tr,
td,
thead,
tbody {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 16px 24px 16px 24px;
}

th a {
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

svg * {
  transition: fill .2s ease;
}

.filters-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
}

th a:hover>svg * {
  fill: #333333;
}

thead tr {
  height: 36px;
}

#bodytable tbody {
  display: block;
}

.table-header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.table-body {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

.header-cell {
  background-color:#f8f8f8;/* older browser */
  background:linear-gradient(#f8f8f8,#f8f8f8 )no-repeat center / 100% 100% ;/* firefox understands this */
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-width: 330px;
}

.body-cell {
  min-width: 330px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-body">
  <table id="bodytable">
    <thead class="table-header">
      <tr>
        <th class="header-cell col1">One
          <a>
            <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="4px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 4 20" enable-background="new 0 0 4 20" xml:space="preserve">
        <circle fill="#666666" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
        <circle fill="#666666" cx="2" cy="10" r="2"/>
        <circle fill="#666666" cx="2" cy="18" r="2"/>
       </svg>
          </a>
          <div class="filters-menu"></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```