# Bootstrap table border not showing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

Table border is not showing in Firefox. Shows border, if **tfoot** or **tr** inside **tfoot** removed.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total 1 person</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="test">
                <td>Mohammed</td>
                <td>mytestmail@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Check it on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammedmt/dojek6en/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Borders not shown in Firefox with border-collapse on table, position: relative on tbody, or background-color on cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517127/borders-not-shown-in-firefox-with-border-collapse-on-table-position-relative-o)

Comment: A </div> is missing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dojek6en/22/ 
here is the updated code. Please have a look.

Comment: @VivekKumar  Thanks, it works :)

Comment: @VivekKumar: This still have issue. Footer is grouped with header, so it appears before the body. If the tfoot moved to the end (after body), footer appears at right place but no border is shown.