# Table headers position:sticky and border issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that I'm trying to get sticky headers, following [this article](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/).  Except my table style has the headers with a border at the top and bottom.

The part I do not understand is that the top/bottom borders applied to the `th` scroll away with the rest of the table instead of staying with the "stuck" header cells.  Is there anything that can be done about this?

Working sample can be found here: https://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/MNKqQY?editors=1100#0

```js
let string = ''
console.log("oj")
for(let i=0; i<100; i++) {
  string += `
        <tr>
          <td>Malcolm Reynolds</td>
          <td>Captain</td>
          <td>9035749867</td>
          <td>mreynolds</td>
        </tr>
  `
}
document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML += string
```

```css
.table-sticky-container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.table-sticky {

  th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    border-top: 1px solid red !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table-sticky-container">
  <table class="table table-sticky">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Malcolm Reynolds</td>
          <td>Captain</td>
          <td>9035749867</td>
          <td>mreynolds</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Border style do not work with sticky position element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361698/border-style-do-not-work-with-sticky-position-element)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can add

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

But unfortunately it looks bad, a better solution will be adding a workaround using a pseudo-element.

```css
th:after,
th:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

th:before {
  top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

th:after {
  bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```css
.table-sticky-container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.table-sticky th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

th:after,
th:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

th:before {
  top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

th:after {
  bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<div class="table-sticky-container">
    <table class="table table-sticky">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Malcolm Reynolds</td>
          <td>Captain</td>
          <td>9035749867</td>
          <td>mreynolds</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zoe Washburne</td>
          <td>First Officer</td>
          <td>8908980980</td>
          <td>zwashburne</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kaylee Frye</td>
          <td>Engineer</td>
          <td>6678687678</td>
          <td>kfrye</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Malcolm Reynolds</td>
          <td>Captain</td>
          <td>9035749867</td>
          <td>mreynolds</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zoe Washburne</td>
          <td>First Officer</td>
          <td>8908980980</td>
          <td>zwashburne</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kaylee Frye</td>
          <td>Engineer</td>
          <td>6678687678</td>
          <td>kfrye</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

The second solution

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-sticky thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 red, inset 0 -2px 0 red;
}
```

Comment: that works.  I notice somehow I can see the content "behind" my header in the gap where the border "should" be.  So I set the "top" and "bottom" to -1px.

Comment: I added a second solution width box-shadow.

Comment: I understand graphical purists ;)

Comment: As @sarthakc suggested, combined the 1st solution with `border-spacing: 0;` and it looks good !

Comment: Whats' wrong with first solution, in my project I have everything the same, but when I scroll site thead is sticky but background-color of thead disappear

Comment: Thank you for a great solution. It's the only one out of many I've found that works correctly with `rowspan` and `colspan` inside the `thead` (only after adding `th {position: relative}` to the code though).

Answer (score 39):

You can add

```
.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the optimal solution.

Comment: this is way better, the effect you see content behind the header is very minimal.

Comment: My only issue with this is that if you have borders > 1px then you end up with a very slight inconsistency in your border widths.

Comment: How do you deal with the fact that now borders are a minimum of 2px? I cannot for the life of me making the borders thinner.

Comment: amazing thank you, I was racking my brain on this one

Comment: THIS ! Finally. All the solutions seem overly complex. I knew I would fine the easy solution if I keep searching. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `border-collapse` and draw the lines as follows :

```
td, th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid grey
}

th {
    background-color:#c5e8ec;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another working solution](https://codepen.io/yesbutwait/pen/zgJQKd) (tested at latest Chrome and FF) - wrap th/td content with divs and use those divs borders instead of cell's borders.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="cell">head1</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="cell">head2</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="cell">head3</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="cell">head4</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="cell">head5</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td, th {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 0;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

td .cell {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
}

th .cell {
  border-left: none;
}

td:first-child .cell,
th:first-child .cell {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```