# Vuetify datatable how fit the table vertically along with pagination footer stick to the bottom

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am having a hard time making the [vuetify datatable](https://codepen.io/sarojsasmal/pen/XWmLavM) fit to the screen along with pagination footer sticking to the bottom of the screen regardless of number of rows in the data table.

I tried to set the footer to use following css to always stick to the bottom but it doesn't work as expected

```
  #table .v-data-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#table .v-data-table__wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: auto scroll;
}
```

When the data table has more number of rows, it simply pushes the pagination control to the bottom and it is not visible until I scroll it down to the very bottom.One thing I also tried to do is to set a **fixed height** for the data table but this is not ideal because of the device sizes, for larger screen size it behaves really weird.

I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/sarojsasmal/pen/vYNqeZP) with a simple data table, when we increase the number of rows from pagination control, it loads more number of rows and the footer simply hidden because of height.
I expect the data table to have a height for the content so that user can scroll through the rows and the pagination control should always stick to the bottom no matter what the device size is.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help or give me any pointers on this.

Comment: That should help `#table .v-data-footer { position: fixed;  bottom: 0; width: 100%; justify-content: center; }`

Comment: This should make the footer stick to the bottom but the main content won't be not scrollable. It needs a height to be set so that the content can be scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the v-data-table fit screen. you can use `position: fixed` to the footer, and set a margin to wrapper (same as footer height):

```
#table .v-data-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

#table .v-data-table__wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/hans-felix/pen/MWaMENQ

Comment: Thanks for answer! Really appreciate it but I want the headers to be fixed and the wrapper area to be scrollable along with fixed footer!

Comment: you can make the top section fixed as the same footer way

Comment: what if there are more element before the table, I want to make the header fixed but the content shhould be scrollable. for example this one https://codepen.io/sarojsasmal/pen/PoPrdrV?editors=1100 . But the problem is that If I provide a fixed height, it won't scale across the devices. for large devices there are empty space inside the table content. Please try to zoom out the codepen to see the issue.

Comment: See for this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57170489/10424385), the same can be done with footer.

Answer (score 0):

your just code
1.code v-data-table in v-container1
2.put ||style="height: xxxx"|| class="elevation-1 overflow-y-auto" || in v-data-table 
3.code v-pagination in v-container2
try it!!!!!

```html
<template>
<div>
      <v-container>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="items"
          :page.sync="page"
          :items-per-page="5"
          class="elevation-1 overflow-y-auto"
          :search="search"
          hide-default-footer
          @page-count="pageCount = $event"
          style="height: 300px"
        >
        </v-data-table>
      </v-container>
      
      <v-container>
        <div class="text-center pt-2">
          <v-pagination
            v-model="page"
            :length="pageCount"
          ></v-pagination>
        </div>
      </v-container>
</div>

</template>
```

Comment: If I provide a static height then the data table height will always be 300px. Which is not ideal.