# Non-transparent white background but keep borders on table

Tags: css, transparency

I have almost successfully made the left columns of my table sticky, so that the rest can be scrolled. This, however, has created a new problem: the table background is white, which means scrolled cells transpire underneath the sticky cells (see screenshot 1). To resolve this, I've made the background of the sticky cells non-transparent by using `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);`. But this also removes the borders of the sticky cells (see screenshot 2). Both variants are ugly.

I've tried adding `border:1px solid #cdcdcd;` (even adding `!important`) to the sticky cells but the borders are still invisible. Any suggestions?

Here's the entire formatting applied to the table:

```
div#scrollable {
   overflow-x: scroll;
}
table#stats {
   border-collapse:collapse;
   width:100%;
}
table#stats th.sticky, td.sticky {
   position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
   position: sticky;
   left: 0;
}
table#stats td.sticky {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
   border:1px solid #cdcdcd !important;
}
table#stats tr#means {
   background-color:#ddffd5;
}
table#stats td.stats {
   border:1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
```

[transparent sticky cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhu43.png)
[non-transparent sticky cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Owz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any other solution than this

```
th.sticky:after, td.sticky:after{
    content : "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;

    background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
```

EDIT : Other solution here [Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361698/border-style-do-not-work-with-sticky-position-element)

Comment: Thanks! I changed the bottom position to -1px to level it perfectly with the cell border. Any idea how to also create a vertical "border" as the visual effect is still not to my taste?

I've tried the following: `th.sticky:left, td.sticky:left {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
}`

but to no avail.

Comment: You can use pseudo classes :before to do it but maybe you have other best solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361698/border-style-do-not-work-with-sticky-position-element

Comment: Yes! This does work! I only need to figure out which borders to add to get it right in my case now. Thank you.