# "sticky" position not keeping border as scrolls and not hiding elements it scrolls over

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to essentially "freeze" the entire left column of my table so that when users scroll across (if there are many items in the table) they will know which one they are looking at.

Here's the table as is:
[image]

Here's the code for the table headers (i.e. each cell in the first column):

```
export const TDHeader = styled.td<any>`
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid ${theme.gray.lightmedium};
  border-style: ${props => (props.borderTop ? "solid" : "none")} solid
    ${props => (props.borderBottom ? "solid" : "none")}
    ${props => (props.hideLeft ? "none" : "solid")};
  padding: 13px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  svg {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
`;
```

and they, of course, are rendered as needed based on how many sensors. However, adding the "position: sticky" and "left: 0" caused my table to act like so:

[image]

None of the colors from the original cell are retained, the border on the right is not coming with it, and it is not stacking over the text in the main part of the table.

Comment: isnt it sticky already  in final image but with a transparent background? Try some opaque background and i think you should achieve what you looking for?

Comment: @RohitKhanna ahh you're right. That leads me to my next question - why isn't the border  on the right tacking along with it? The border just stays put

Comment: @JimmyBlundell Use `border-collapse: separate` to solve the border issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50361698/14967413.