# how to make z-index property work on table-border

Tags: html, css, border, z-index

I have an html file which contains a table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <style media="screen">
      body {font-size: 120%;}
      td, th {text-align: center;}
      .stickyth th {position: sticky; top: -1px; background: #ccc; z-index: 3;}
      .col5-out {position: relative; z-index: 2;}
      .col5-inner {background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #6303B1, #ff0099); max-width: 25%; left: -22px; border-radius: 25%; transform: rotate(-23deg); top: -11px; position: absolute;}
      .col5-content {font-size: 75%; padding: 1px 6px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <tr class="stickyth">
              <th>column 1</th>
              <th>column 2</th>
              <th>column 3</th>
              <th>column 4</th>
              <th>column 5</th>
              <th>column 6</th>
              <th>column 7</th>
              <th>column 8</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>

      </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

The table has one `<tr>` element with css property `position:sticky;` (the first row of the table), and the other `<tr>` tags are example rows (every cell in these rows has "some text" text in it).

In column number 5, I added something like a purple tag for each cell of the regular `<tr>` tag, not the first row of the table.
see the first picture.

[image]

The problem is that even though I did wrote `z-index: 3;` for the first row, the purple tag is visible where the border of the table is (see the second picture).

[image]

I tried some things that didn't work:

1. change the numbers of the `z-index` property, and even adding `z-index` with lower numbers for other related elements in the file
2. write `.stickyth` instead of `.stickyth th` in the `style` tag at the top of the file
3. add another `div` tags in the first row and in the purple tag.

I didn't succeed to achive what I wanted.

How can I make the purple tag be **under** the table border of the first row?

Comment: why is there so many rows (and column) ? is that important and usefull for understanding your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you set your border for that row to another color, you'll see the border scroll with the page while the row stays in place. Bootstrap collapses the table borders and this is where the problem begins.  If you separate the border it'll fix the problem, but you'll have to make some other styling changes because you'll see a space between the cells.  This link will shed some light on the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361698/border-style-do-not-work-with-sticky-position-element

Comment: @MisterJojo relating to your question: you are right that there are a lot of rows, and this is because I wanted the page to be long enough so all the `sticky` thing would work well. About the columns, this is what I have in my project... 8 columns is not so much I think..

Comment: So this is indeed a test to reassure yourself, and it therefore has no place here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit odd, but what seems to be happening is that the border scrolls even when the element itself is inside a sticky one which has stuck.

This snippet does a slightly hacky workaround - putting a left side border on each th which has a light grayish color. If you put it just on the 5th th it tends to look just slightly different from the others, so this makes them all the same.

The after pseudo element does not scroll so the purple bits go underneath OK.

```css
tr.stickyth th:nth-of-type(n)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.5px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <style media="screen">
      body {font-size: 120%;}
      td, th {text-align: center;}
      .stickyth th {position: sticky; top: -1px; background: #ccc; z-index: 3;}
      .col5-out {position: relative; z-index: 2;}
      .col5-inner {background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #6303B1, #ff0099); max-width: 25%; left: -22px; border-radius: 25%; transform: rotate(-23deg); top: -11px; position: absolute;}
      .col5-content {font-size: 75%; padding: 1px 6px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <tr class="stickyth">
              <th>column 1</th>
              <th>column 2</th>
              <th>column 3</th>
              <th>column 4</th>
              <th>column 5</th>
              <th>column 6</th>
              <th>column 7</th>
              <th>column 8</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>

      </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked. I wrote "5" in the `(n)` and changed the color to the color of the border (the bootstrap border) and it did exactly what I wanted it to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the border to 0 pixels, you'd get rid of the gap:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <style media="screen">
      body {font-size: 120%;}
      td, th {text-align: center;}
      .stickyth {background: #FFF;}
      .stickyth th {position: sticky; background: #ccc; top: -1px; z-index: 3; border: 0}
      .col5-out {position: relative; z-index: 2;}
      .col5-inner {background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #6303B1, #ff0099); max-width: 25%; left: -22px; border-radius: 25%; transform: rotate(-23deg); top: -11px; position: absolute;}
      .col5-content {font-size: 75%; padding: 1px 6px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <tr class="stickyth">
              <th>column 1</th>
              <th>column 2</th>
              <th>column 3</th>
              <th>column 4</th>
              <th>column 5</th>
              <th>column 6</th>
              <th>column 7</th>
              <th>column 8</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="not-sticky">
              <td>some text 1</td><td>some text 2</td><td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
              <td><div class="col5-out">some text 5<div class="col5-inner"><div class="col5-content">tinytext</div></div></div></td>
              <td>some text 6</td><td>some text 7</td><td>some text 8</td>
            </tr>

      </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes.. You are right, but I do want the border... If I can achive what I wanted, WITH the border, I would prefer to do so, instead of just setting the border to 0. If this is the only option, I will just set the border to 0 as you told me. Meanwhile, I will read more answers. Thank you anyway.