# Background color visible through sticky th

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a sticky header and a few rows with a unique column that spans the entire row and a background color. When scrolling, this background color can be seen over the border color of the thead cells. Is there a way to make the border show over the cell's background color instead?

[image: background showing over border]

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

th, td {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

td[colspan] {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

table thead:first-child th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row1 col 1</td>
      <td>row1 col 2</td>
      <td>row1 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">row2 col 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row3 col 1</td>
      <td>row3 col 2</td>
      <td>row3 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row4 col 1</td>
      <td>row4 col 2</td>
      <td>row4 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row5 col 1</td>
      <td>row5 col 2</td>
      <td>row5 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row6 col 1</td>
      <td>row6 col 2</td>
      <td>row6 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row7 col 1</td>
      <td>row7 col 2</td>
      <td>row7 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row8 col 1</td>
      <td>row8 col 2</td>
      <td>row8 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row9 col 1</td>
      <td>row9 col 2</td>
      <td>row9 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row10 col 1</td>
      <td>row10 col 2</td>
      <td>row10 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row11 col 1</td>
      <td>row11 col 2</td>
      <td>row11 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row12 col 1</td>
      <td>row12 col 2</td>
      <td>row12 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row13 col 1</td>
      <td>row13 col 2</td>
      <td>row13 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row14 col 1</td>
      <td>row14 col 2</td>
      <td>row14 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row15 col 1</td>
      <td>row15 col 2</td>
      <td>row15 col 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes an idea found in a comment in [Border style do not work with sticky position element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361698/border-style-do-not-work-with-sticky-position-element) but adding an alteration to the width defined for the borders - halving them so the two together make the required 2px.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  position: relative;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

td[colspan] {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

table thead:first-child th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row1 col 1</td>
      <td>row1 col 2</td>
      <td>row1 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">row2 col 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row3 col 1</td>
      <td>row3 col 2</td>
      <td>row3 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row4 col 1</td>
      <td>row4 col 2</td>
      <td>row4 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row5 col 1</td>
      <td>row5 col 2</td>
      <td>row5 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row6 col 1</td>
      <td>row6 col 2</td>
      <td>row6 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row7 col 1</td>
      <td>row7 col 2</td>
      <td>row7 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row8 col 1</td>
      <td>row8 col 2</td>
      <td>row8 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row9 col 1</td>
      <td>row9 col 2</td>
      <td>row9 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row10 col 1</td>
      <td>row10 col 2</td>
      <td>row10 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row11 col 1</td>
      <td>row11 col 2</td>
      <td>row11 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row12 col 1</td>
      <td>row12 col 2</td>
      <td>row12 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row13 col 1</td>
      <td>row13 col 2</td>
      <td>row13 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row14 col 1</td>
      <td>row14 col 2</td>
      <td>row14 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row15 col 1</td>
      <td>row15 col 2</td>
      <td>row15 col 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find this SO question even if my life depended on it!