# Collapsed borders covered by background in Firefox, if surrounded by inline-block and table with caption

Tags: css, firefox, html-table

Apparently I have found the weirdest little Firefox bug:

I have a table with background colors and collapsed borders.
To put a border around it, it is wrapped in a `div` with `display: inline-block`.

This works fine, and it also works when I show it in a table.
But when the surrounding table has a `caption`, the backgrounds cover the borders.
(Here the background color is transparent, so light borders can be seen.)

[image: screenshot]

This is similar to the decade old Firefox bug [688556](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688556).
(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517127).)
But that is supposed to happen only, when the cells are relatively positioned.

Is there some workaround except avoiding the `caption` tag?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
}
table td {
  padding: 10px;
}
caption{
  font-weight: bold;
}


table.inner > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(255,165,0, .9);
}
table.inner > caption {
  color: red;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  padding: 20px;
}


table.outer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
table.outer > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
table.outer > caption {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="outer">
  <tr>
    <td>outer table without caption</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <table class="inner">
          <caption>inner</caption>
          <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
          <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>

<table class="outer">
  <caption>outer</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>outer table with caption</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <table class="inner">
          <caption class="inner">inner</caption>
          <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
          <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **isolation** css property. This will isolate each table and may fix your problem.

> The isolation CSS property determines whether an element must create a new stacking context. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  isolation: isolate; /* added */
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  isolation: isolate;
}

table td {
  padding: 10px;
}

caption {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table.inner>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.9);
}

table.inner>caption {
  color: red;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  padding: 20px;
}

table.outer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table.outer>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

table.outer>caption {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="outer">
  <tr>
    <td>outer table without caption</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <table class="inner">
          <caption>
            inner
          </caption>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>

<table class="outer">
  <caption>
    outer
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <td>outer table with caption</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <table class="inner">
          <caption class="inner">
            inner
          </caption>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gladly, it even works, when `isolation: isolate` is added only to the inner table. (Because one does not always control the styles of the outer one.)