# How to do a border-radius on inner table cell, honouring background property

Tags: css

I have a need to have a table with 3px padding (plus border) and background (only) on the th.

Here is what I am using:

```
 <table class="data" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Example Here</th>
            <th scope="col">Another Here</th>
            <th scope="col">One Here</th>
            <th scope="col">Two Here</th>
            <th scope="col">Three Here</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>This is some text.</td>
            <td>Data table with data.</td>
            <td>Data here.</td>
            <td>And more here.</td>
            <td>This is legit!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is some text.</td>
            <td>Data table with data.</td>
            <td>Data here.</td>
            <td>And more here.</td>
            <td>This is legit!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is some text.</td>
            <td>Data table with data.</td>
            <td>Data here.</td>
            <td>And more here.</td>
            <td>This is legit!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is some text.</td>
            <td>Data table with data.</td>
            <td>Data here.</td>
            <td>And more here.</td>
            <td>This is legit!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
/* Data Table */
table.data {width:100%;border:1px solid #dfdfdf;color:#303030;border-radius:4px;padding:4px;line-height:25px;}
table.data thead tr {background:#eee;width:100%;}
table.data tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background:#efefef;}
table.data thead tr th:first-of-type {border-top-left-radius:4px;}
table.data thead tr th:last-of-type {border-top-right-radius:4px;}
table.data td, table.data th{padding:3px 8px 4px;}
</style>
```

I have created a table with border which appears to create a rounded corner with border but the background doesn't change. So obviously using the same background as border results in no change. I've also played with `background:radial-gradient` with no solution, yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe this how you are expecting the border to be. The only thing I have done is to removed the `border:1px solid #dfdfdf` from `table.data` class and added in the `table.data td, table.data th` class. Below is the complete changes:

```css
table.data {
  width: 100%;
  color: #303030;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

table.data thead tr {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
}

table.data tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #efefef;
}

table.data thead tr th:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

table.data thead tr th:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

table.data td,
table.data th {
  padding: 3px 8px 4px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<table class="data" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Example Here</th>
      <th scope="col">Another Here</th>
      <th scope="col">One Here</th>
      <th scope="col">Two Here</th>
      <th scope="col">Three Here</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some text.</td>
      <td>Data table with data.</td>
      <td>Data here.</td>
      <td>And more here.</td>
      <td>This is legit!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some text.</td>
      <td>Data table with data.</td>
      <td>Data here.</td>
      <td>And more here.</td>
      <td>This is legit!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some text.</td>
      <td>Data table with data.</td>
      <td>Data here.</td>
      <td>And more here.</td>
      <td>This is legit!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is some text.</td>
      <td>Data table with data.</td>
      <td>Data here.</td>
      <td>And more here.</td>
      <td>This is legit!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:** Attaching the screenshot taken in the Firefox browser(109.0.1) in Mac OS(64-bit).

[image]

Comment: OK so yes that works, in Safari, in Firefox the background expanse leaves the borders edge and fills as though there is no border-radius. Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/k806jcwv/

Comment: @CraigFairhurst, this looks like a firefox bug which is not fixed yet. link: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688556
Also, there are some workaround given in the following link which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517127/borders-not-shown-in-firefox-with-border-collapse-on-table-position-relative-o

Comment: Yes it would appear to be a (10+ year old) bug. I updated the fiddle, what did I miss? https://jsfiddle.net/k806jcwv/1/

Comment: So, the property 'border' property needs to be applied in the 'tables th, td'. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sam_phillemon/mhkw0534/5/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work in Firefox 109.0.1 (64-bit) on Mac OSX.

Comment: Well, I am not sure why it is not working on your end. But here's the code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-kate-f1puck?file=/style.css
So I only did a minor change only to your fiddle code. I have removed the ```table.data th{border:1px solid #aaa;}``` and added the border ```border:1px solid #dfdfdf;``` in ```table.data td, table.data th ``` class. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox. I'll update if I find something, position: static has been mentioned in the links provided, for example.

Comment: Still not found a solution for this, let's hope with the (10+ year old) bug being entered someone will see this in the future.

Comment: I have tried Firefox 109.0.1 (64-bit) on Mac OS and it looks like it is working on my end. I have added the screenshot from my firefox browser.

Comment: In your image there is an overlap of grey, it's very feint. Squint..(or change `#eee` to `yellow`)

Comment: I see what you mean. So If you need a workaround for the Firefox browser alone. Then I tried multiple things and this one is working a little better. But keep in mind that it is just a workaround not the perfect solution and might impact other browsers as well. So What I found is wrapping the table in another div and adding CSS to hide the extra background color with overflow: hidden. Here's the code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-kate-f1puck?file=/style.css